# Play video using Html5 in Android

Tags: android

is it possible to play video using Html5, if possible please te;; me the process.
I have tryed with Video tag but it is not playing in emulator.
Video format is Mp4.

Please help on this if any one knows?

Answer (score 0):

yes is possible, most mobile browsers support html5 (so video tag too), I suggest you to add also a .3gp  file for older phones, as you can see here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html  deconding 3gp is widely supported,  you may pay attention to the codec, because decoding mp4 or 3gp encoded with H.264/AVC is not supported on older phones.

Answer (score 0):

Set a WebChromeClient on the WebView. It should be able to read it (Froyo and later)